# How to let <f:facet> contain multiple components? It shows only the first

Tags: jsf, facet

I use `<f:facet>` to create a table header and I want a symbol beside it. However, it doesn't seem to work well. The symbol is not rendered.

JSF:

```
<h:column id="subject_column">
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:commandLink value="Subject" id="sort_by_subjects"
                   action="#{xxx.sort}">
      <f:param id="sortBySubject" name="sortBy" value="SUBJECT"/>
    </h:commandLink>
    <span>${isAscending}</span>
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{email.emailSubject}"/>
</h:column>
```

`${isAscending}` contains the arrow symbol `↑` and represents the order. I would like to show it beside `<h:commandLink>`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `<f:facet>` can have only one child. Wrap multiple children in a `<h:panelGroup>`.

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:commandLink ... />
            <h:outputText ... />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>
    ...
</h:column>
```

Comment: I'd like to mention that at least in Mojarra 2.2.5 that is not so. You can have multiple children in a `f:facet`, and Mojarra creates an implicit wrapping `UIPanel` for them. This does go against JSF spec.

Comment: I've noticed this is not always the case with PrimeFaces components. They seem to sometime allow multiple children on a facet

Comment: @Kukeltje: it's indeed fixed somewhere between March 2012 and now, I only can't tell yet when. Perhaps later and then I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `<f:facet>` can have only one child. Wrap it in a `<h:panelGroup>` or `<h:panelGrid>`.

Comment: just suggest an edit (smal, very small) enhancement to the accepted answer